# Blink a mesh renderer 4 times

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to blink my gameObject's mesh renderer 4 times with a delay of 0.25 seconds. The mesh renderer gets disabled in the beginning but never re-enables and never blinks. I thought the best way would be to use a for loop.

```
    MeshRenderer mr;

    void Start () {
        mr = this.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        StartCoroutine (Blink ());
    }

IEnumerator BlinkLid () {
       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        mr.enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.25f);
        mr.enabled = true;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to wait before the next iteration!

```
IEnumerator BlinkLid () 
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
   {
        mr.enabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.25f); // or 0.125f if it shall take 0.25 in total
        mr.enabled = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.25f); // or 0.125f if it shall take 0.25 in total
   }
}
```

otherwise you wait to set it to `enabled = true` but immeditely go to the next iteration where again you set it `enabled = false` ;)